# How to pass array of values from multiselect into jquery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-multiselect

I'm using jQuery multiSelect and want to pass the selections to my update script.

Here's my ajax call

```
var newnotesecurity = $("#nt_newnotesecurity").serializeArray();

$.ajax({
  url: 'notes-savenewnote.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    cache: false,
    companyid: companyid,
    entitytype: entitytype,
    entityid: entityid,
    noteinitials: newnoteinitials,
    notetext: newnotetext,
    notetags: newnotetags,
    notesecurity: newnotesecurity
  },
  success: function() {
    // blah
  },
  error: function(){
    // blah
  }
});
```

nt_newnotesecurity is the multiselect object.  Obviously serializeArray is not working for me.  It's just my latest attempt to get this working.

I end up passing in this:

```
notesecurity[0][name]=nt_newnotesecurity&
notesecurity[0][value]=2&
notesecurity[1][name]=nt_newnotesecurity&
notesecurity[1][value]=14
```

but I'd like to pass in this

```
nt_newnotesecurity=2&nt_newnotesecurity=14
```

or I'd be just as content to pass in a single value that I can explode later on, like this

```
notesecurity=2-14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget#retrieve-all-selected-values-) for the multiselect plugin, just calling `val()` should get you all the values

```
var newnotesecurity = $("#nt_newnotesecurity").val();
```

Comment: Thank you.  That works perfectly.  I coulda swore I had tried that early on, but I must've had other problems with my code at that point.    Now I feel silly.

Comment: Although this was five years ago, I'm pretty sure the reason it didn't work for me initially was because I neglected to add multiple='multiple' to the select tag.  I know because it happened to me again this morning.